# Long running Asyncio server, reload certificate

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, tcpserver

I have a custom TCP server implemented with Python 3.5's asyncio library. I also use Lets Encrypt certificates for SSL encryption of the communication with the server. Lets Encrypt only issues certificates valid for 90 days and there is a good chance my server will not be restarted for a longer period of time than this.

I am generating the SSLContext like this:

```
ssl_context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
ssl_context.load_cert_chain(certfile='path/to/cert', keyfile='path/to/key')
```

And the server like this:

```
server = asyncio.streams.start_server(self._accept_client, ip, port, loop=self.loop, ssl=ssl_context)
```

When the certificate expires, existing connections continue to function but new connections will (correctly) fail. Apparently the `SSLContext` or the server itself keeps the certificate and key files loaded in memory because updating the files on disk does not solve the problem.

I've read the Python documentation quite a bit and found no solution mentioned. One idea I've had is to try call the `ssl_context.load_cert_chain()` on a regular interval with the hope that this will update cert and key. I can't look at the source of the `load_cert_chain` function to determine it's behavior as it is apparently written in C, and the documentation doesn't specify the behavior of calling this function once the context has been passed to the server.

Is there a way to update the certificate and keyfile loaded in the `SSLContext` at runtime without completely stopping and restarting the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am fairly sure that keeping a copy of the context you use and calling the method to reload the cert chain will work fine.  At least at the C openssl API level that's a reasonable thing to do and it doesn't look like python does anything to break that.

Comment: Trying this... will let you know in 90 days!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no API in asyncio.Server to update the SSL certificate when the server is live, you've got two solutions:

You can use the SNI callback to update the certificate during the SSL handshake, but it will only work with clients supporting SNI.
This means that for each client supporting this feature, a callback of your choice will be called and may return a SSLContext object that will be used to establish the connection with the client. You can make this callback so it will read the certificate/key files at each call, or be reloaded when needed by a trigger of your choice.

To setup the callback, see: https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLContext.set_servername_callback

The other solution is more complicated to get right with the current state of the asyncio API: it might break if the internal implementation of asyncio changes, and I didn't check how it would work with a proactor loop. However, it will work with any kind of client.

You can create a new server with the new context, but using the socket of the first server:

```
# This will create a new server with the current socket, and setup what's required to use the new callback.
new_server = await asyncio.create_server(callback, None, None,
                   sock=old_server.sockets[0], ssl=new_context)

# Ensure that when cleaning the old_server, it doesn't try to close the socket we kept
old_server.sockets = []
old_server.close()
await old_server.wait_closed()
```

At one point during create_server(), asyncio will start to answer to new connections with the new ssl context. Note that once a connection is started and passed to your callback (_accept_client), it is in practice independent of the server which called it, so it will left any existing connection untouched.